# A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1] : Need Help Parsing Json

Tags: json, api, parsing, gson

I've been trying to parse this but am getting the error : Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

```
    System.out.println("Which city would you like to find the weather for?");
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        city = s.nextLine();
    }

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&APPID=26aa1d90a24c98fad4beaac70ddbf274")).build();
    client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .thenApply(HttpResponse :: body)
        //.thenAccept(System.out::println)
        .thenApply(Main::parse)
        .join();
}


public static String parse(String responseBody) {
    JSONArray weather = new JSONArray(responseBody);
    for (int i = 0; i < weather.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject weatherObj = weather.getJSONObject(i);
        int id = weatherObj.getInt("id");
       // int userID = weatherObj.getInt("userId");
       // String title = weatherObj.getString("title");

        System.out.println(id + " "/* + title + " " + userID*/);

    }
return null;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

since your url returns an object, not array, try

```
 JSONObject weather = new JSONObject(responseBody);
```

Answer (score 1):

The API you are calling doesn't return an array but an object, so you have to deserialze to an object and not to an array. The data you are after is probably the `weather` property of that response object.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseBody);
JSONArray weather = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("weather");
```